# cUrl ubuntu теряется параметр

Tags: ubuntu, curl

Передаю cUrl запрос через терминал на сайт, с двумя параметрами, а доходит только первый параметр
Пример: `curl http://127.0.0.1/api?test1=1&test2=12345`

В терминале так же высвечивается:

```
Done      sudo curl http://127.0.0.1/api?test1=1
```

Второй параметр теряется... 
Вбивая запрос в браузере всё работает как надо
Google ничем не помог

Comment: может в ковычки обернуть надо? curl "http://127.0.0.1/api?test1=1&test2=12345"

Comment: Пробовали добавить кавычки? что бы было так curl "http://127.0.0.1/api?test1=1&test2=12345" как в примере на http://dev-lab.info/2012/11/команды-curl-для-отправки-запросов-метод/

Comment: И вправду, кавычки помогли, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо: `curl "http://127.0.0.1/api?test1=1&test2=12345"` 
все URL с символом `&` должны быть в кавычках. man bash :)

> Если команда завершается управляющим оператором `&`, интерпретатор
>   выполняет команду в фоновом режиме в порожденном интерпретаторе.
>   Командный интерпретатор не ждет завершения команды, а статус выхода в
>   этом случае - 0.
>
> Символ, разделяющий слова, если он не замаскирован. Один из следующих
>   символов: `|  & ; ( ) < > пробел табуляция`